# TSQL: Get minimum of each group without using inner queries

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

It's kind of hard to explain this but say I have this table

```
DateTime    ID# Type       Cost
8/1   8pm   1   Activate    2
8/1   8pm   1   Add         15
8/1   10am  1   Add         30
8/1   1pm   1   Use         NULL
8/5   6pm   1   Use         NULL
8/5  11pm   1   Add         14
8/12 9am    1   Use         NULL
8/15 11am   1   Add         100
8/15 1130am 1   Add         10
8/15 5pm    1   Use         NULL
8/1   8pm   2   Activate    2
8/1   8pm   2   Add         15
8/1   10am  2   Add         30
8/1   1pm   2   Use         NULL
8/3   6pm   2   Use         NULL
8/3   12pm  2   Add         14
8/12 9am    2   Use         NULL
8/15 11am   2   Add         90
8/18 5pm    2   Use         NULL
```

I did a group by CardNumber

```
1
2
```

Then I did:

```
SELECT CardNumber
       ,SUM(Case when Type = 'Add' then Cost ELSE 0 END) as totalMoneyAdd
FROM Table 
Group by CardNumber

1   169
2   105
```

Now I want to add another column WITHOUT using inner queries or nested queries so that for each ID# it will have an aggregate sum column where it will only take the sum of each ID#'s initial add for each day.

For example, ID#1 is active in 8/1, 8/5, 8/12, and 8/15. If you look closely, on 8/1, the initial 'add' for Id#1 is 15 dollars, for 8/5 initial is 14, for 8/12 is 0, for 8/15 is 100. Adding all those initials would be $129 for ID#1. Same calculation would apply in Id#2

SO overall I want:

```
1   169  129
2   115  119
```

And I want to achieve this WITHOUT using inner queries or nested queries, meaning by only adding a column like

```
SELECT CardNumber
       ,SUM(Case when Type = 'Add' then Cost ELSE 0 END) as totalMoneyAdd
       --,Add calculations here to calculate this new column
FROM Table 
Group by CardNumber
```

I'm thinking of using some sort of partition, but that would require me to create a nested query or query inside a from clause. I want to know if this is achievable.

Comment: I'd use a common table expression or two.

Comment: Is this possible without using CTEs

Comment: I don't think so. If you try to add a windowing function to this it throws: `Windowed functions cannot be used in the context of another windowed function or aggregate.`

Comment: @johnc why are you opposed to subqueries or CTEs? Often they're the only solution to a problem because single-level queries are not expressive-enough.

Comment: @Dai I'm not oppose actually, just this proprietary software I use builds this whole query internally and project the result in pretty pictures. The problem with this is I can only add calculation in a column. The program will ask for my source table, then it would ask for fields. In the field, I can I either put the actual column name or some calculation like Sum(case when... then 1 else 0 end) then it would build the query internally and translate it into intuitive graphical based data. I'm trying to make a work around to see if I can achieve this with limitation I have.

Comment: @JohnC Can you create a `VIEW` and specify that as the source-table in the query builder tool? Another option is a scalar UDF, but that would be inefficient.

Comment: @Dai You would need permission to create a view in the database or contact one of our DBs. This isn't really a must have for customers, but I thought it would be cool for customers to see this data about how people's average initial transactions say something about their spending style in pretty pictures. Since this is not possible, I'd pass this one. Thanks for all  help

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right you need to use partition by to resolve this issue. As far as inner join or nested sql is concerned, you need to use nested query for these type of query.
my anwser is not matching since think there is some error in you calculation. I have created two sample queries for you. First with inner query and second without inner query as below. I have split date and time into two column as i don't have the physical table. Please do necessary conversion for it. In the case of second query it is not giving the resultset as required by you but please check if you can use it in you case as you only need to group it by id and sum other column to get the desired result.

Query 1:

```
select id,sum(cost) totalmoneyadd, sum(totalmoneyinit) totalmoneyinit
from
(
    select 
    id
    ,cost
    , case when rank() over (partition by id,date order by id,date,time) =1 then cost else null end totalmoneyinit 
    from
    (
        select '8/1' date,20 time, 1 id,'Activate' type, 2 cost
        union
        select '8/1',20,   1,'Add', 15
        union
        select '8/1',10, 1,'Add',         30
        union
        select '8/1',13,   1,'Use',       NULL
        union
        select '8/5',18,  1,'Use',         NULL
        union
        select '8/5',23,   1,'Add',         14
        union
        select '8/12', 9,    1,'Use',         NULL
        union
        select '8/15', 11,   1,   'Add',         100
        union
        select '8/15', 11.5, 1,'Add',         10
        union
        select '8/15',17,    1 ,  'Use',  NULL
        union
        select '8/1',20,   2,'Activate',    2
        union
        select '8/1',20,   2 ,'Add',         15
        union
        select '8/1',   10,  2,'Add',         30
        union
        select '8/1',13,   2,'Use',         NULL
        union
        select '8/3',18,   2,'Use',         NULL
        union
        select '8/3',   12,  2   ,'Add',         14
        union
        select '8/12', 9,    2   ,'Use',         NULL
        union
        select '8/15', 11,   2   ,'Add',         90
        union
        select '8/18', 17,    2   ,'Use',         NULL
    )A
    where type='Add'
) B
group by id
```

Query 2:

```
select 
case when rank() over (partition by id,date order by id,date,time) =1 then id else null end id
,case when rank() over (partition by id,date order by id,date,time) =1 then sum(cost) over (partition by id,date order by id,date,time desc) else null end totalmoneyadd 
, case when rank() over (partition by id,date order by id,date,time) =1 then cost else null end totalmoneyinit 
from
(
    select '8/1' date,20 time, 1 id,'Activate' type, 2 cost
    union
    select '8/1',20,   1,'Add', 15
    union
    select '8/1',10, 1,'Add',         30
    union
    select '8/1',13,   1,'Use',       NULL
    union
    select '8/5',18,  1,'Use',         NULL
    union
    select '8/5',23,   1,'Add',         14
    union
    select '8/12', 9,    1,'Use',         NULL
    union
    select '8/15', 11,   1,   'Add',         100
    union
    select '8/15', 11.5, 1,'Add',         10
    union
    select '8/15',17,    1 ,  'Use',  NULL
    union
    select '8/1',20,   2,'Activate',    2
    union
    select '8/1',20,   2 ,'Add',         15
    union
    select '8/1',   10,  2,'Add',         30
    union
    select '8/1',13,   2,'Use',         NULL
    union
    select '8/3',18,   2,'Use',         NULL
    union
    select '8/3',   12,  2   ,'Add',         14
    union
    select '8/12', 9,    2   ,'Use',         NULL
    union
    select '8/15', 11,   2   ,'Add',         90
    union
    select '8/18', 17,    2   ,'Use',         NULL
)A
where type='Add'
```